# Session returns null Get request however in Post returns the session correctly in Next.js in server side (nextAuth)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to get the session data such as id, name, etc on the server-side but returns null in the terminal.
In the GET Method session is null, however, in POST method returns the session perfectly.

```
    import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;
  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const session = await getSession({ req });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(session));        //Returns null
        const jobs = await prisma.jobs.findMany();
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, jobs });
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          success: false,
          message: error.message,
        });
      }
}

case "POST":
  try {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(session));   // here returns the session
    if (!session || session.role != 2) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        msg: "You are not authorized to perform this action",
      });
    }
```

**[...nextauth].js**
...nextauth.js file applying credentials provider, I am not sure if I have to implement anything else in addition

```
    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.API_URL}/auth/authentication/login`,
            {
              email: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password,
            }
          );

          if (!user.data.user) {
            return null;
          }

          if (user.data.user) {
            return {
              id: user.data.user.id,
              name: user.data.user.name,
              surname: user.data.user.surname,
              email: user.data.user.email,
              role: user.data.user.role,
            };
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.name = user.name;
        token.surname = user.surname;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.name = token.name;
        session.surname = token.surname;
        session.email = token.email;
        session.role = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    encryption: true,
    maxAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
});
```

Comment: It must be your calling code (client-side) not sending along a session in Get requests, as from just this snippet alone it should be getting the session. Have you tried hitting the endpoint manually in a HTTP client like Postman?

Comment: @svict4 I tried also, but the session goes null, how to make the request with the session?
It is weird because the post request it is done with session

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. Can you try moving `const session = await getSession({ req })` just before the switch statement?

```
...
const session = await getSession({ req });

console.log(JSON.stringify(session));

switch (method) {
  ...
}
....
```

Comment: I tried but still is null, maybe has to do something with the ...nextauth or something else. 
However it is weird because in POST request works well, and in GET, request does not work properly.